# Mongoose query asyncronously

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I am trying to perform multiple `Model.count()` mongoose queries asynchronously. However, I want to be able to stop and return in case any of these queries return an error. This is my code:

```
var User = require('../models/user').model;
module.exports = {
getStatistics: function(req, res) {
        var response = {};
        User.count({}, function(err, count) {
            if(err || !count) res.status(500).json({error: 'unknown error'});
            response.total_count = count;
        });
        User.count({platform: 'iOS'}, function(err, ios) {
            if(err || !ios) res.status(500).json({error: 'unknown error'});
            response.ios_count = ios;
        });
        User.count({platform: 'Android'}, function(err, android) {
            if(err || !android) res.status(500).json({error: 'unknown error'});
            response.android_count = android;
        });
        res.return(200).json(response);
    }
}
```

However, I get the `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent` error. Is there a way to do it or do I have to run them synchronously?

Answer (score 2):

Call 2nd and 3rd functions inside each callback `function(err, data)`:

```
User.count({}, function(err, count) {
  if(err || !count) res.status(500).json({error: 'unknown error'});
  response.total_count = count;

  // Call your 2nd function.
  User.count(..} // and so on.
});
```

You can also use [mongoose promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) for that, then just chain them with next.

```
User.count({}).exec()
  .then((data) => {
    // 2nd function.
    return User.count({...});
  })
  .then((...) => {...} // and so on.
```

**Edit:**

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent
```

You are getting this error because you are sending up to 4 responses to the user, coming from your parallel requests (3 from possible `if(error ||`).

You should also make sure to `return` every `res`, otherwise it'll keep processing your request even if it fell under your error conditional.

Comment: But this will make them synchronous. Isn't there a way to make them asynchronous?

Comment: @SalmaFG this is 100% asynchronous. I think you are mixing concepts (sequential != synchronous)

Comment: @SalmaFG see my edit, added useful information that might help you get your problem resolved

Comment: I have originally returned every response and had the same problem. Can you explain how the code is executed asynchronously if it is written in this sequential fashion? I'm confused.

Comment: @SalmaFG Javascript callbacks are asynchronous. http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/